# Which one is better Approach?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Which one is better design Approach 1 or Approach 2, i have to maintain the title field in all the languages.

Approach 1:

```
heads (table)
- id
- status
- created_at
- updated_at

heads_metadatas (table)
- id
- head_id
- language_id
- title
```

Approach 2:

```
heads (table)
- id
- language_id
- title
- status
- created_at
- updated_at
```

Comment: What is the M:N-ness relationship between the tables in approach 1? If you add another language, with a different title, to `heads_meta` do you have it refer to the existing `heads` or do you create a new one? Can one language have a different status to another one?

Comment: Is there a 1:n relationship between `heads` and `head_metadata`? Why did you separate them in the first place?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have updated my question, basically i have to maintain title field in all the languages.

one to many relationship between heads and head_metadas table

Comment: @CaiusJard  status, created_at, updated_at will repeat for all the entries so i decided to separate these fields.

Comment: @CaiusJard No, one language can not have a different status to another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you say in your comments, Approach 1 is the only way to go:

- There are many languages that a Title may be translated into
- All translations of a Title share a common Status and Created/Updated [see note] dates

Realistically, if you try approach 2 then your primary key is a composite of id + language_id and you run the risk that one day someone will create a different status in each of two records referring to the same head

Personally, I think creation date, status etc is metadata, so I don't think the naming of your entities is great - I'd perhaps have `heads` and `head_translations`.

Note: I'd also have a created/updated (and deleted if you're soft deleting) date set on both tables..